# String does not take value from EditText

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I´ve got a database android app and I was wondering why there is nothing in my database after an insert. Now, I found my problem but I can´t track it.

```
        EditText ename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetName);
        final String name = ename.getText().toString();

        EditText ezeit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetDatum);
        final String zeit = ezeit.getText().toString();

        EditText egenaueres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetGenaueres);
        final String genaueres = egenaueres.getText().toString();

        Button bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEreignis);
        System.out.println("sdssssssssssssssssss" + name + zeit + genaueres);

        bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    db.insertereignis(name, zeit, genaueres);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Insert des Ereignisses fehlgeschlagen!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my insert method. At the `System.out.println`, `name`, `zeit` and `genaueres` are null but I don´t understand why.

Here is my xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/eetName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name des Ereignisses"
        android:textColor="@color/black" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eetDatum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eetName"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Datum des Ereignisses"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eetGenaueres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eetDatum"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Genaueres zum Ereignis"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btEreignis"
        style="@style/darkbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Speichern" />
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a EditText,

> EditText ename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetName);

It is blank by default and you are accessing it's text value at that time. which is wrong.

You need to make little change as below,

```
    final EditText ename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetName);
    final EditText ezeit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetDatum);
    final EditText egenaueres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetGenaueres);
    Button bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEreignis);
    System.out.println("sdssssssssssssssssss" + name + zeit + genaueres);

    bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String name = ename.getText().toString();
            String zeit = ezeit.getText().toString();
            String genaueres = egenaueres.getText().toString();
            try
            {
                db.insertereignis(name, zeit, genaueres);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Insert des Ereignisses fehlgeschlagen!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You need to get the EditText's value at the onClickListener() method.

Comment: Ya need to make those edittexts a final variable, unless they are declared as class variable

Comment: @ChorWaiChun, Yes agree with you. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Ok thanks. Was wondering about that a long time. My problem now is, that when I insert two lines in my db, there is always rowid = 1. Do you know why?

Comment: Well, not the String, the EditText -.- they have to be final so that inner class can access them

Comment: @user896692, you should ask a new question. so that other users can also get chance to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{   
      EditText ename,ezeit,egenaueres;
      Button bSave;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           ename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetName);
            ezeit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetDatum);
            egenaueres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetGenaueres);
             bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEreignis);
         bSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String genaueres = egenaueres.getText().toString();
                Log.e(genaueres.toString(), "genaueres");
                final String name = ename.getText().toString();
                Log.e(name.toString(), "name");
                final String zeit = ezeit.getText().toString();
                Log.e(zeit.toString(), "zeit");
                System.out.println("sdssssssssssssssssss" + name + zeit + genaueres);
                try{
                    db.insertereignis(name, zeit, genaueres);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Insert des Ereignisses fehlgeschlagen!");
                }
            }

         });


    }
}
```

try this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplest and formated way to use.

**Global(Class level)** declaration of variables.

```
EditText ename,ezeit,egenaueres;
Button bSave;
public static String name = null,zeit = null,genaueres = null;
```

In **onCreate()** method.

```
ename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetName);
ezeit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetDatum);
egenaueres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eetGenaueres);
bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEreignis);

bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        try
        {
            name = ename.getText().toString();
            zeit = ezeit.getText().toString();
            genaueres = egenaueres.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("==================\nName : " + name +"\nZeit : "+ zeit +"\nGenaueres : "+ genaueres +"\n"==================);

            db.insertereignis(name, zeit, genaueres);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NullPointerException npe){
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

There is a way to use code.